# JSON: add new json data to MySQL

Tags: java, web-services

I write a Java program to keep information about the login information for the Internet access information for a student and save the information to the database.

My table is like this:

```
mysql> desc data_log_test;
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| studentID   | varchar(40) | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| details     | json        | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| date_insert | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
```

Information that will be store in the details should be :

```
 {
    "time_login": 1, 
    "ipInt": 167772160, 
    "urlAccess": "https://google.com", 
    "duration": 30
 }
```

This information will be keep updating from time to time.

My question - is it possible to add only the details information in the table?

I want for particular studentID, it can have more than 1 details.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the details information" you want to omit `date_insert`? It is impossible because it declared as required. You cant have more then one record per `studentID` because it declared as primary key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want the student to have more details, then you should implement a ManyToOne connection ([see the reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html))

```
CREATE TABLE student_detail (
    ID        varchar(40),
    studentID varchar(40),
    detail    json,
    INDEX studentID_idx (studentID),
    FOREIGN KEY (studentID)
        REFERENCES data_log_test(studentID)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

PS:

- I recommend you to rename your `data_log_test` table to `student` since it stores students
- I recommend you to rename `studentID` field of `student` to `id`
- Also I recommend you to follow the common naming conventions, like table names and columns should be `named_like_this` so not `studentID` but `student_id` (take a look at [Snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case))